# Entity Framework : How can i translate group by to entity framework statement

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

```
SELECT 
    MAX([VersionCode]) AS VersionCode, 
    [PackageName]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Application]  
GROUP BY 
    [PackageName]
ORDER BY 
    [VersionCode] DESC
```

This sql statement allows me to select the maximum version of an application by grouping.

I have difficulty to translate it to use Entity Framework, mainly in group by section:

```
GroupBy ( a=>a.PackageName )
```

Then I don't know how to get the Application by the highest version.

Comment: At this stage, I can do this ordering a group  Applications.OrderByDescending(x=>x.VersionCode).GroupBy(x=>x.PackageName).Select(x=>x) but how do i get application with the highest version code in the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you `GroupBy`, you need to project the output with `Select`. As you want the highest version, you use `Max`:

```
var results = db.Applications
    .GroupBy(a => a.PackageName)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        PackageName = g.Key,
        Version = g.Max(a => a.VersionCode)
    });
```